# QSerialPort only reads correctly after second open

Tags: c++, serial-port, qt5

I have a program that uses serial input. It's installed on quite a few machines with both Win7 and Win10. On some machines I have the strange issue that when opening the serial port at first it reads strange/incorrect values, mostly 0xff. When I close the port and reopen it, it works correctly.

```
    m_port = new QSerialPort( info ); // some info from QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

    if( m_port->open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )
    {
        m_port->setBaudRate( m_baudRate );
        m_port->setDataBits( m_dataBits );
        m_port->setParity( m_parity );
        m_port->setStopBits( m_stopBits );
        m_port->setFlowControl( QSerialPort::FlowControl::HardwareControl );
        m_port->clear();
     }
```

}

So am I just lucky that it works on like 90% of my installations and it's missing some explicit setting or might it be a bug in Qt? (5.6.0 msvc 2013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely what the problem here is that you're setting the settings on the serial port *after* you have opened it.  Therefore, there's a small period of time where your settings could be in an odd state.  It works the second time you open the port because the settings have been correctly set from the first time you opened the port.

`QSerialPort` will apply the serial port settings when `open` is called.

```
m_port = new QSerialPort( info ); // some info from QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

m_port->setBaudRate( m_baudRate );
m_port->setDataBits( m_dataBits );
m_port->setParity( m_parity );
m_port->setStopBits( m_stopBits );
m_port->setFlowControl( QSerialPort::FlowControl::HardwareControl );

if( m_port->open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )
{
    m_port->clear();
}
```

Comment: Sleeping for a bit before calling clear() won't hurt either.  Still, resynchronizing with the data sent by the device is likely to be necessary.  Worst-case he'll have to instruct the user to turn on the device only after starting his program.

Comment: That sounds plausible Will accept the answer as soon as the client in Japan switches on teamviewer and I can test the fix.

Comment: Well it wasn't that but I found the bug. This is still more right than it was before,